# Python Walk directory structure and zip sub directories

Tags: python, python-2.7

I ran the following code:

```
import zipfile
import glob
import datetime
import os 
from collections import defaultdict
from shutil import copyfile

src = 'X:\\' 

for name in glob.glob('X:\*'):  
    print name

dict_date = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))
for fil in os.listdir(src):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(src, fil)):
        date, logs = fil.split('_')[0], fil.split('_')[2]
        dict_date[date][logs].append(fil)

for date in dict_date:
    for logs in dict_date[date]:
        try:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(src, date, logs))
            except os.error:
            pass
        for fil in dict_date[date][logs]:
            copyfile(os.path.join(src, fil), os.path.join(src, date, logs, fil))



for date in dict_date:
    with ZipFile(os.path.join(path, '{0}.zip'.format(date)), 'w') as myzip:
        for logs in dict_date[date]:
            for fil in os.listdir(os.path.join(path, date, logs)):
                if fil.endswith('.log'):
                    myzip.write(os.path.join(path, date, logs, fil))
```

Here are the results :

```
>>> 
X:\082012
X:\092012
X:\20120830
X:\20120830_7Days_ISDA_Logs_HS.zip
X:\20121001
X:\20121002
X:\20121003
X:\20121004
X:\20121005
X:\20121006
X:\20121007
X:\20121008
X:\20121009
X:\20121010
X:\20121011

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\tyoffe\Desktop\isda_zip.py", line 31, in <module>
    with ZipFile(os.path.join(path, '{0}.zip'.format(date)), 'w') as myzip:
NameError: name 'ZipFile' is not defined
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(path, '{0}.zip'.format(date)), 'w') as myzip:
```

or you should do:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
```

Comment: Sorry one more. Where do I need to define 'path'. Thanks so much in advanceTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\tyoffe\Desktop\isda_zip.py", line 31, in <module>
    with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(path, '{0}.zip'.format(date)), 'w') as myzip:
NameError: name 'path' is not defined
>>>

Comment: @user1741381 You should probably define `path` before line 31 (where you use it). The `path` in question is the first parameter to `os.path.join()`. It doesn't look like it's defined anywhere.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks to both for showing me my oversights!